# Powershell to show AD group with disabled account - count?

Tags: powershell

How can I modify the below code so that it can go through all AD groups in the domain with a disabled AD account and its count total?

Code I have:

```
$groupName = 'Developer Group'
$count = Get-ADGroup -Identity $groupName -Property Members |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty members |
            Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Where-Object {-not $_.Enabled} |
            Measure-Object |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
"Group '$($groupName)' has $($count) disabled accounts."
```

Ideally, the Output is in .CSV file with this column:

```
AD group name, Total AD account, Total Disabled AD account
```

Comment: I would probably start from finding disabled users first and then getting their membership: `Get-ADUser -Filter "enabled -eq '$false'" -Properties memberOf`

Comment: What would happen for groups having members than than users, i.e.: users and computers, should the computer objects add to the Total AD Count ?

Comment: Yes, for anything that is disabled.

Comment: Then use `Get-ADObject` rather than `Get-ADUser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not make it a hassle of working with a bunch of calculated properties, I recommend the use of a `[PSCustomObject]` for this.

First, filter for all groups using `Get-ADGroup -Filter '*'`. Then use a call to `Get-ADObject` to get a list of accounts. Finally, construct the the `[PSCustomObject]` with the properties and values you're after:

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter '*' 
foreach ($group in $ADGroups)
{
    $DN = $group.DistinguishedName
    $filter = $null = Get-ADObject -Filter "memberof -eq '$DN'" -Properties 'UserAccountControl'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ADGroupName   = $group.Name
        TotalAccounts = $filter.Count
        TotalDisabled = ($filter | Where-Object -Property 'UserAccountControl' -EQ 514).Count
    }
}
```

`Get-ADObject` doesn't return the property of `Enabled`, but it does return `UserAccountControl` (*when specified via `-Properties`*) which you can filter for the disabled accounts via its value of `514`; this is what's used for the `TotalDisabled` count.

Comment: In fact.. you really should do `[bool](UserAccountControl -band 2)`, because it is the `ACCOUNTDISABLE` (2) flags value that shows if an object is disabled or not. See [UserAccountControl property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties) and [Converting UserAccountControl Attribute Values in Active Directory](http://woshub.com/decoding-ad-useraccountcontrol-value/). Value 514 is just a `NORMAL_ACCOUNT -bor ACCOUNTDISABLE`, but Get-ADObject can also return other objects than normal accounts.

Comment: @Abraham, the script somehow failed for AD group name with apostrophe?
Get-ADObject : Error parsing query: 'memberof -eq 'CN=John's One drive data,OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com' Error Message: 'syntax 
error' at position: '23'

Comment: Thanks Theo. @SeniorSystemsEngineer, add `-replace "'","''"` to `$DN = $group.DistinguishedName`, it's not letting me edit my post at the moment so I can't update it. You're just essentially escaping the single quotes (*apostrophe*) by doubling it up: `$DN = $group.DistinguishedName -replace "'","''"`.

Comment: Thank you @AbrahamZinala, I appreciate your assistance in this matter.